# Реализовать сброс таймера

Tags: c#, таймер

Есть таймер, кнопка запуск\стоп и кнопка сброс, все традиционно. Но я не могу придумать как его сбросить.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace lab6
{
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void tickTimer(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        long tick = DateTime.Now.Ticks - date.Ticks;
        DateTime stopWatch = new DateTime();
        stopWatch = stopWatch.AddTicks(tick);
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss:fff}", stopWatch);
    }
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) //это кнопка старт\стоп
    {
        timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;
        timer.Interval = 1;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(tickTimer);
        button1.Text = timer.Enabled ? "Стоп" : "Старт";
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //button3 это кнопка, отвечающая за сброс. Тут собственно метод нужон.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас привязка идет к моменту запуска программы, немного странная реализация. Но велосипед можно не изобретать и использовать специально предназначенный для этого класс [`Stopwatch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8).

**Поправил код:**

```csharp
using System.Diagnostics;
```

```csharp
public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // это надо сделать 1 раз, а не каждый раз, когда вы запускаете таймер.
        // еще этот код лучше унести отсюда в обработчик события Form.Load
        // потому что в конструкторе окна в целом опасно вставлять код
        timer.Interval = 1;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(tickTimer); 
    }
    private void tickTimer(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // вынес обновление текста таймера в отдельный метод
        RefreshTimer();
    }
    private void RefreshTimer()
    {
        // мне не нравится эта реализация, возможно есть способ проще
        // но код писал на коленке в блокноте, не мог тестировать
        DateTime date = new DateTime(stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        label1.Text = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss:fff}", date);
    }
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = !timer.Enabled;
        if (timer.Enabled)
            stopWatch.Start();
        else
            stopWatch.Stop();
        button1.Text = timer.Enabled ? "Стоп" : "Старт";
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopWatch.Reset();
        RefreshTimer(); // и вот почему я вынес в отдельный метод
    }
}
```

**Рекомендация:** называйте методы с большой буквы, а переменные и поля с маленькой.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования моего таймера:

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer();//создаем инстанс
timer.SetTime(30,0); //выставляем на 30 минут
timer.StepMs = 33; //Выставляем шаг таймера (как часто вызывается TimeChanged)

//Подписываемся на событие TimeChanged и в нем обновляем значение лейбла
timer.TimeChanged += () => Label1.Text = timer.TimeLeftMsStr; 

// Подписываемся на событие окончания таймера и реагируем на него сообщухой
timer.CountDownFinished += () => MessageBox.Show("Timer finished the work!"); 

timer.Start(); //стартуем
```

И не забываем вызвать `Dispose();` когда таймер уже не нужен.

Сброс можно сделать по вызову метода reset() или restart()

---

Код самого таймера:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CountDownTimer : IDisposable
{
    public Stopwatch _stpWatch = new Stopwatch();

    public Action TimeChanged;
    public Action CountDownFinished;

    public bool IsRunnign => timer.Enabled;

    public int StepMs
    {
        get => timer.Interval;
        set => timer.Interval = value;
    }

    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private TimeSpan _max = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000);

    public TimeSpan TimeLeft => (_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) > 0 ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) : TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0);
    
    private bool _mustStop => (_max.TotalMilliseconds - _stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) < 0;

    public string TimeLeftStr => TimeLeft.ToString(@"\mm\:ss");

    public string TimeLeftMsStr => TimeLeft.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.fff");

    private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeChanged?.Invoke();

        if (_mustStop)
        {
            CountDownFinished?.Invoke();
            _stpWatch.Stop();
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public CountDownTimer(int min, int sec)
    {
        SetTime(min, sec);
        Init();
    }

    public CountDownTimer(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        SetTime(ts);
        Init();
    }

    public CountDownTimer()
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        StepMs = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerTick);
    }

    public void SetTime(TimeSpan ts)
    {
        _max = ts;
        TimeChanged?.Invoke();
    }

    public void SetTime(int min, int sec = 0) => SetTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(min * 60 + sec));

    public void Start() {
        timer.Start();
        _stpWatch.Start();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        timer.Stop();
        _stpWatch.Stop();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Reset();
        Pause();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _stpWatch.Reset();
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        _stpWatch.Reset();
        timer.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose() => timer.Dispose();
}
```